# Reciprocal Shifted Log-Normal Distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a log-normal distribution, let $k\geq0$ be a real value and let $Y=\frac{1}{X+k}$. What is the name of the $Y$ distribution other than 'reciprocal shifted log-normal'? What is the mean of $Y$ in terms of $X$'s mean and variance?

Thanks!

Comment: If $k=1$ then $Y$ is a logistic normal function. In other cases you may relate it to a more general Johnson's $S_b$-distribution (see this [similar question on stats.stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/331751/reciprocal-of-shifted-lognormal-random-variable)). There is no known analytical expression for the mean of $Y$.

Answer (score 1):

If $k=1$ then $Y$ is a logistic normal function. In other cases you may relate it to a more general Johnson's $S_b$-distribution (see this [similar question on stats.stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/331751/reciprocal-of-shifted-lognormal-random-variable)). There is no known analytical expression for the mean of $Y$.